# Typescript - Self-Executing Anonymous Functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

How I can create self-executing anonymous functions using type script?

For example

```
(function() {
 var someClass = {
 }
}.call(this));
```

I want a built a plugin that may work for Node.js, also for fron-tend as well.

Comment: no because all answers cannot produce about output

Comment: I actually don't understand what you mean by that.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
/**
 * Self executing anonymous function using TS.
 */
(()=> {
    // Whatever is here will be executed as soon as the script is loaded.
    console.log('executed')
})();
```

> I want a built a plugin that may work for Node.js, also for fron-tend as well.

In that case you should compile your TypeScript in AMD and use an AMD loader on the frontend, like http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

On the server side, you would need to use `requirejs` node package as well to load the file. Take a look at this: http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html

Basically there are two ways to compile TS to JS, using AMD, which is browser compliant, or using CommonJS, which is node.js compliant. Loading an AMD script in the browser or in the server needs to use an AMD compliant loader, and *requirejs** is one of them. (the most famous/used I'd say)

Answer (score 3):

First rule in TypeScript: **Any valid JavaScript is valid TypeScript.**

No, there are are no special way to write Self-Executing Anonymous Functions in TS as of right now.

But, below is some code that might be of some use in your situation.

Every Class in TS is compiled to a (Named) Self-Executing Anonymous Functions, which returns a function.

Example:

```
//ts
class someClass {
  someProperty = "this is a property";
}
```

Translates to

```
//js
var someClass = (function () {
    function someClass() {
        this.someProperty = "this is a property";
    }
    return someClass;
})();
```

Hope this is of some help.

Comment: I wish the **Any valid JavaScript is valid TypeScript** rule was true. TypeScript is great but I get soo frustrated with type exceptions for perfectly valid JavaScript... I am currently researching how to create jQuery plugs in TypeScript... Nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

An self-executing, immediate, recursive top-level React function in Typescript:

```
(function handleAutomatonTypeChange(newtype: AutomatonType) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Automaton automatonType={newtype}
               onAutomatonTypeChange={handleAutomatonTypeChange} />,
    document.getElementById('automaton')
  );
})('diadic');
```

Answer (score -3):

```
(function(){
    document.body.innerHTML = "Self Calling Function";
}.call(this));
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers. Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.